# symfony2 blank page on web hosting server

Tags: symfony

I try to deploy my project on my distant web server. I think the sf2 installation is ok I have the app_dev.php and the config.php pages, the check.php doesn't return me any error and I set up the acl on the directories app/cache and app/logs.

but I cant have any of my pages from my controllers. If I try something like .../Symfony/web/app_dev.php/myurl I have a blank page.
What can I do? thanks in advance

Comment: are the dependencies installed properly ??

Comment: Do you have some log from your application? If yes, can you add it in your question please? If not, maybe it's your webserver which is not well configured?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely there's a php error, you should check your web server/php error log files. The exact location of those depends on configuration, ask your hosting provider if you can't find them yourself.

As a wild guess, check the permission on the `app/cache` folder - this is a common problem I believe. You should always run `app/console cache:clear --no-debug --env=prod` with the webserver user.

Answer (score 0):

You may also check whether mod_rewrite is enabled in your server.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you have checked the obvious but app_dev contains the following:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
|| isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
|| !in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array(
    '127.0.0.1',
    '::1',
))
) {
header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.');
}
```

Make sure to add your IP, remove the IP block altogether or come up with a login solution.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the blank pages simply executing this command on the project root:

```
app/console assets:install web
```

Answer (score 0):

i opened my Linux terminal and execute :

```
php app/check.php
```

it showed me ERROR:

- date.timezone setting must be set

  > Set the "date.timezone" setting in php.ini*

**i set server timezone and restart my server, my blank page gone, and symfony 2.7.3 version start working**